# How to sort a tensor by first dimension in libtorch in C++?

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

I have the following 2D tensor and I would like to sort by the first dimension:

```
torch::Tensor tensor = torch::randn({3, 4});
```

Comment: looking for [at::sort](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/function_namespaceat_1ad421d1c91fbbf5fa42bd20b1273b7c4f.html), [torch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sort.html#torch.sort)?

Comment: have you checked this one? https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classat_1_1_tensor.html